# What is an initial skeleton of the website called? A Framework?

Tags: php, programming-practices, project-management, websites

I am building a website but I am wondering can I call the initial set of pages a framework?

Say I have a project to build a website for a school. Before I start implementing the requirements I have to build a basic structure which includes initial homepage, navbar etc. just basic set-up pages and structure.

The website will be built upon this framework or skeleton. Is it correct to call this a framework?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: I'd call it a skeleton.

Comment: A framework is more of a programming *tool* than anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Framework has come to mean something like angular.js or .NET, so it would perhaps be misleading to use that word. (Only because of current trends in programming culture, though; it's perfectly reasonable usage otherwise.)

You could refer to your initial set of files as a **scaffolding,** or as **mock-ups** if they only exist to show an initial visual design.

Comment: I understand what you mean. What if I call it {WebApplication name} Framework instead of just framework so it makes it obvious that I am only referring to my web application

Comment: That makes a degree of sense. The main thing to consider, I suppose, is who gets to see that - and whether they will be confused by it. I'm afraid that some clients are prone to being awkward when they don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

As with any naming question it's hard to say that anything is incorrect, but it would definitely be misleading and/or confusing to use the term "framework" for this. The term "framework" normally refers to something like ASP.NET which provides necessary features like session management, but doesn't impose any particular page hierarchy. Using "skeleton" seems fine though.

Answer (score 1):

What Ixrec said.

I would like to add that I would call it a *site map*, because that's what a sitemap basically is.

The site map may have a public part, which you might want to include in an actual "site map page" presented to the visitors, and a private part, which might contain things like administration pages etc. the existence of which you probably would not want visitors to know.